# Jump to an absolute page from the beginning of the document

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I jump to a specific page from the beginning of the document, such as page 20, When on page 10 the numbering starts from 1?

I tried the following code, and it jumped to page 30, which is 20 pages after the numbering started again, but not from the beginning of the document.

```
Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToPage, with:=wdGoToAbsolute, Name:=20
```

Comment: Do you have a section break where the pages start renumbering?

Comment: @Comintern Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're using `Name:=20`

Instead, use `Count`:

```
Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToPage, with:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=20
```